# execute script when directory listing by .htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have a http server (apache HTTPD v2.4) where directory listing is enabled. I configured it to use the 'fancy-index' from https://github.com/Vestride/fancy-index, and works great. However, its searching function didn't give what I was looking for.

I'd like to configure the webserver such that if I goto http://mywebserver.com/someDir/*?list, it will return a list of all the files in someDir in a "file, filesize" format.

Or, if I goto http://mywebserver.com/someDir/essay2020*.txt?list , I'll get a custom list of all essay2020*.txt files. Or some form of a simple regex: say "essay2020[0-2]*.txt".

I can write a php/perl/python script that can read a directory and return the 'file, filesize' list. But how do I configure the .htaccess to call this script? Do I have to muck around with 'RewriteRule'? or something special?

As an added note, I'm not limited to modifying .htaccess only. If I can do all of this by modifying the httpd.conf, I'm open to that suggestion too.

Thanks.

Comment: Using the rewrite engine for this is fine, IMHO, but you will need to use a RewriteCond to check the query string content, a RewriteRule can not do that on its own. httpd.conf vs. .htaccess are just different places to configure this - if you can do it in the former, than that would be preferbable to using .htaccess files.

Comment: Can I use the **RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} list=**, and if found write a RewriteRule that will call '/search.php?var=$1' where $1 is %{REQUEST_URI}? If so, how can I write this? So basically, if the end of URI is _?list_, then call 'search.php?var=URI'.

Comment: Should be `^list$` if you only want to match that specific query string. (The question mark is not part of it, I think.) Yes, in theory it should work that way.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^list$`, `RewriteRule .* /search.php?var=%{REQUEST_URI}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in Comments by **CBroe** did it. By just modifying the *apache2.conf* file to add:

```
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^list$
        RewriteRule .* /search.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

within my <VirtualHost>, I'm now able to forward everything to search.php, where there I can parse and do what needs to be done. All w/o revealing search.php's existence. Thanks.